How can i automate viewing files in react-native application?
I am new to programming. I'm trying to display drawings in my react-native application. I can't seem to automate this in any way and I don't want to believe there is no way to do it other than specifying each file in the code. It is not possible to view the folders directly, because it gives me an error with the permission, and as far as I know, the application can't even do that.
Anyone have any ideas? There are many files and they will change roughly every year. Rewrite because of it approx. 200 paths is really unimaginable. I would like the application to automatically detect changes in folders, that probably wouldn't work. Something that would work better.
I was also thinking of naming the files the same as the new ones, what would only allow the files to be reuploaded, replaced. Is there no other option?
const folderStructure = [
  {
    type: 'folder',
    name: 'drawings',
    files: [
      {
        type: 'folder',
        name: 'NX4e',
        files: [
          {
            type: 'folder',
            name: 'NX4e (GTW)',
            files: [
              { 
                type: 'file', 
                name: '91100-N7000-MAIN CONNECTORS.pdf', 
                path: 'drawings/NX4e/NX4e (GTW)/91100-N7000-MAIN CONNECTORS.pdf',
              },
              {
                type: 'file',
                name: '91100-N7000-MAIN.pdf',
                path: 'drawings/NX4e/NX4e (GTW)/91100-N7000-MAIN.pdf',
              },
              {
                type: 'file',
                name: '91200-N7000-FRONT GAMMAII.pdf',
                path: 'drawings/NX4e/NX4e (GTW)/91200-N7000-FRONT GAMMAII.pdf',
              },
              {
                type: 'file',
                name: '91210-N7000-FRONT NU 2.0 MPI.pdf',
                path: 'drawings/NX4e/NX4e (GTW)/91210-N7000-FRONT NU 2.0 MPI.pdf',
              },
        
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

